# Is it possible to determine the wallet ID that received my fund from one account to another?

Tags: blockchain, coinbase.com

I am new to bitcoin. I opened an account with Coinbase and also an account with Blockchain.  I transferred about $35 worth bitcoin from Coinbase to an address I generated from my Blockchain wallet. HOwever, after the transaction was completed, I was not able to locate the funds in Blockchain. I have the transaction history and even the address, but am not able to unlock it with my own wallet ids.  Blockchain support has been non-exist, so i'm writing on this blog to see anyone has similar experience and can share their thoughts on this.  I presume i will not be able to get the $35 back, but thought i give this forum a try. Thanks in advance! L

Comment: Can you link the txid here? Does the address you paid to show up in your blockchain.info wallet? Did you triple check that it matched when you copy/pasted it at the time of transfer?

Comment: Hi Chytrik - i think i used the QR Code to send the payment. Honestly, I can't recall how it occurred. i just know the address that i sent to b/c it's in the transaction history.  I tried to add it to my wallet in Blockchain, but i get a message saying this is a Watch Only address.